# Is there a way to conditionally display the slidesPerView in React Swiper based on the Device screen resolution?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, responsive-design, swiper.js, react-swiper

```
<Swiper
          slidesPerView={
            window.innerWidth <= 550
              ? 1
              : window.innerWidth <= 720
              ? 2
              : window.innerWidth > 720
              ? 3
              : 0
          }
          spaceBetween={30}
          pagination={{
            clickable: true,
          }}
          modules={[Pagination]}
          className="mySwiper"
        >
          {cardApi.map((card) => (
            <SwiperSlide>
              <div key={card.name} className="testimonial__card">
                <div className="testimonial__card-top">
                  <img src={card.profilePic} alt={card.name} />
                  <div>
                    <h4>{card.name}</h4>
                    <p>{card.position}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="testimonial__card-bottom">
                  <p>{card.comment}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
```

In the lines of code above, I'm trying to conditionally set the slides of a swiper based on the screen size (in order to make it responsive). The goal is to make 3 slides display on a (1280px) screen, 2 slides on a (720px) screen and lower, and a single slide on a (550px) screen and lower.

The code shared above does work eventually, but that is only after I refresh the page. I am hoping there'll be a better way to approach this issue where the slides will automatically adjust to the conditions immediately after resizing the screen without having to refresh the page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what others have recommended, you need to setup an `eventListener` that listens for the `resize` event . This can be done inside a `useEffect`. On resize, it will then set the slides per view.

The function that sets the slidesPerView:

```
const setSlidesPerview = () => {
    setSlides(
      window.innerWidth <= 550
        ? 1
        : window.innerWidth <= 720
        ? 2
        : window.innerWidth > 720
        ? 3
        : 0
    );
  }
```

The useEffect :

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // Initially set the amount of slides on page load
  setSlidesPerview();
  // Add the event listener on component mount
  window.addEventListener("resize", setSlidesPerview);
  // Remove the listener on unmount
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", setSlidesPerview);
  };
}, []);
```

Here is an example on codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-currying-uoxpw1?file=/src/App.js:538-772

Answer (score 0):

export const sliderSettings = {
slidesPerView: 1, // Corrected property name
spaceBetween: 10, // Corrected property name
breakpoints: {
480: {
slidesPerView: 1,
},
600: {
slidesPerView: 2,
},
750: {
slidesPerView: 3,
},
1100: {
slidesPerView: 4,
},
},
};

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).